# null false doesn't trigger error in rails and unique doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rails not null / unique in migrations doesn't trigger error :S

```
class CreateDeditProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dedit_projects do |t|
      t.string :name, :null => false
      t.string :uid, :unique => true
      t.boolean :status

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

empty name doesn't trigger error. Neither does duplication of uid.

This is what I see in schema.db

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150410105216) do

  create_table "dedit_projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.string   "uid"
    t.boolean  "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

hm, I need to add indexes somewhere I guess? Shouldn't that be automatic?

Not null problem is bogus though.

Comment: What makes you think that `t.string` takes a `:unique` option?

Comment: @muistooshort common sense?

Comment: Empty and null and not the same thing

Comment: @FrederickCheung I realised that, db has "" not null. That solves the first problem. Regarding second problem unique should be declared outside create_table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails automatically adds index on id and references and maybe on some other types. If You want to add new index, You can create a migration:

```
  def change
    add_index :dedit_projects, :uid, unique: true
  end
```

You can also use validations `validates_uniqueness_of` and `validates_presence_of` in models. Although I don't understand why doesn't it work as it is :)

Comment: Adding that migration doesn't work either... something is fishy here.

Comment: I guess this migration won't add index if table already has non-unique fields. Or does it?

Comment: Found a somehow related question. Seems like you must create an index for a unique field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568761/does-in-rails-making-a-column-unique-at-a-db-level-require-it-to-become-an-index @salivan

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness is a property of the index so you need either a separate call to `add_index` or write it like so

```
create_table :dedit_projects do |t|
  t.string :uid, index: {unique: true}
  ...
end
```