# Does in Rails making a column unique at a db level require it to become an index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I want to make a table column unique at a database level, does this require this column to also become an index?

I have a column called username that I want to be unique but it does not require to be an index (logging in is done based on email address, which is already an index).

So at a model level I have added:

```
validates :username, presence: true,
                     length: { maximum: 15 },
                     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

But what should I do within the migration file? 
I understand I can add to the migration file:

```
add_index :users, :username, unique: true
```

but that would make username also an index, which I don't really need (and I assume will only make the app slower).

I am using SQLite for development (following Hartl's tutorial but adapting the instructions for my own app). 
Probably to make it unique requires it to be an index, but I wanted to be sure. I expect this because on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html 'unique' only is present for the add_index method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the way you make a column unique in the database, you make it a unique index. That is how uniqueness is implemented in dbs. It's put in an index so that its uniqueness can quickly be verified. You're doing it right.

Comment: It's not a universal requirement that it be a unique index -- some databases can implement a unique constraint that is supported by a non-unique index. In general, unique constraints are a different entity to a unique index, even if they have the same affect.